# Dopant in semiconductor

Tags: semiconductor-physics

A dopant with **5** valance electrons is added to a semiconductor (with **4** valance electrons), but now the dopant has **9** electrons in its valance shell. An atom requires only **8** electrons but has an extra one (**8+1**). How does Chemistry react to this?

Answer (score 4):

There is some misconception here. Since you introduce a dopant (e.g. with 5 valence electrons) into a semiconductor crystal (e.g. with 4 valence electrons), it replaces one atom of the semiconductor.

Therefore, locally at one particular lattice site, you have an atom with 5 electrons, of which only four are needed to bond to the neighboring atoms in the crystal. This leaves one weakly bound electron behind. In the case of a dopant, rather than a deep trap, these excess electrons (or holes) are so weakly bound (a few meV) that they are thermally excited (300 K roughly corresponds to 25 meV). Therefore these excess carriers can move freely through the crystal and can carry electric current.

Answer (score 1):

How does chemistry react?

By making the dopant positively charged.

How does it do that? By shifting its extra electron to the conduction band as @engineer pointed out
[image]